# Wordpress & Nginx try_files problem with a website in a subdirectory with permalinks

Tags: wordpress, nginx, subdirectory, permalinks

So, I have a custom website, and a wordpress site located in a different document root, which should work from
https://www.example.com/university-guru/study-abroad

so, the WP site's location is /university-guru/study-abroad and is phisically located in /home/www/blog

the part of nginx's config file for this WP blog is:

```
        location ^~ /university-guru/study-abroad {
                alias /home/www/blog;
                index index.php;

                access_log  /var/log/nginx/blog.log main;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/blog.err.log warn;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite [^/]$ $uri/ permanent;
                }

                try_files $uri $uri/ /home/www/blog/index.php$is_args$args;

                location ~ \/university-guru\/study-abroad.+\.php$ {
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/university-guru/study-abroad(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-fpm-sockets/php74-blog.socket;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
                        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
                        fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
                        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
                        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                }

                add_header Content-Security-Policy "";
                break;
        }
```

The site itself does come up, as well as wp-admin, but the **problem** is that  **permalinks with post name** and most of the URLs (publishing new posts with this permalink setup...) don't work as it doesn't seem to look for the document in a proper form.

For example, clicking on the Hello World article
comes up with a 404 as

> https://www.example.com/university-guru/study-abroad/hello-world/

and the error log throws

> 2021/04/26 21:33:20 [error] 2660705#0: *222405 "/home/www/blog/hello-world/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 116.203.57.178, server: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), request: "GET /university-guru/study-abroad/hello-world/ HTTP/2.0", host: "www.example.com"

I'd say that the proper place to look for the doceument woudl be /home/www/blog/index.php but it adds the url to it

Any ideas?

Comment: One issue is that `try_files` is rewriting the URI to `/home/www/blog/index.php` which looks more like a pathname than a URI, and is then being processed in some other location block.

Comment: Yes, that is the site's document root

Comment: You should use URIs with `try_files`, for example: `try_files $uri $uri/ /university-guru/study-abroad/index.php?$args;`

Comment: Thanks for that. I just tried it - it does make sence as it's all about an URI, but it doesn't "pick it up", the error log still reports

`2021/04/27 21:02:37 [error] 3499151#0: *1137132 "/home/www/blog/hello-world/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 116.203.57.178, server: www.languagecourse.net, request: "GET /university-guru/study-abroad/hello-world/ HTTP/2.0", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/university-guru/study-abroad/"`

meaning,it still adds /hello-world/ to the document root (alias), whic ofc doesn't exist

Comment: Either way, the last argument is a fall back, my first dilema is, why does it look for the file in /home/www/blog/**hello-world**/index.php? I need to strip this off, without destroying /wp-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved this.

The initial problem was that WP is generating a wrong query string as it's residing inside an embeded URL and mostly that was the cause of page not found for post-name permalinks, or anything that is not query string based.

For example, what I needed for "pretty" permalinks, is a fallback to index.php?q=hello-world for the Hello World test article, while it was generating something link index.php?q=/university-guru/study-abroad/hello-world, which was apparently wrong, and resulted with a 404.

So what I did at the end, is to create a capture group in my basic location directive for the WP embeded site, and have try_files use that capture for location, directory and finally fall back to a query argument

```
        location ~ /university-guru/study-abroad(.*)$ {
                alias /home/www/blog/;
                index index.php;

                access_log  /var/log/nginx/blog.log main;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/blog.err.log debug;

                try_files  $1 $1/ /university-guru/study-abroad/index.php?q=$1$args;

                location ~* \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-fpm-sockets/php74-blog.socket;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/university-guru/study-abroad(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/www/blog$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
                        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
                        fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
                        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
                        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                }
        }
```

At this point it seems to be doing the job for me